# How should I approach storing and then retrieving objects from an object array? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Think basic RPG game (I learn best via gamification)...

Keep in mind in game items will be taken, used and dropped all the time in any order... so I am not after finding thing via their numerical position in an array, strictly after finding and utilizing items based on their object variable name or one of it's inherent property values.

I am torn between (a) pushing a game item, as a string variable (like "Poncho")), into a character inventory (array inside an object) and then **somehow** matching that string back up with the actual item (object (like poncho)) to access and utilize its properties/values (like character.inventory.poncho.value)... or (b) push the item as the object itself (like poncho) into the inventory (array) and then **somehow** access it in the array to pull out its values and properties (like name: "Poncho").

I hand stamp my objects as such:

```
var poncho = {
    name: "Poncho",
    value: 3,
    use: function() {}; //do somethin
}

var cigarillo = {
    name: "Cigarillo",
    value: 2,
    use: function() {}; //do somethin
}

var bullet = {
    name: "Bullet",
    value: 1,
    use: function() {}; //do somethin
}
```

Now if I push ("get" in game world) strings into an inventory as such,

```
var character01 = {
    inventory [
        "Poncho",
        "Cigarillo",
        "Bullet"
    ]
}
```

then I can easily access those for display purposes since they are strings. For example:

```
document.getElementById("inventory_display").innerHTML = "Inventory: " + character01.inventory;
```

but I'm stuck on how to extract something like character01.inventory.poncho.value from "Poncho" in the inventory.

If I alternatively push the items in like this:

```
var character01 = {
    inventory [
        poncho,
        cigarillo,
        bullet
    ]
}
```

I'm stuck on how to display name:"Poncho" from the inventory. I know it's there inside [ object Object ], but not sure how to extract.

...

So in a nutshell... Do I push objects into arrays and then **somehow** extract their properties/values? or push a string (name: "Poncho") into arrays and **somehow** deconstruct those backwards to get to their object (poncho) and its values/properties? (Heck is storing/putting objects into an array, for later access even the right approach at all?)

Besides approach, I am interested in the **somehow**. I think if I can get my head around this I'll be able to start laying out a lot more systems (AKA learn more).

Comment: whatever `poncho` is (it's a variable in your last example), it's stored as `character01.inventory[0]`

Comment: @JaromandaX I should have clarified (and now did in an edit to my question) that finding things via their numerical position probably won't be helpful, as the order will constantly be in flux. I need to find them based on their name or baked in unique identifier.

Comment: well, an array wont be helpful then - or you can find in an array of course

Comment: Well I feel horrible. There was a user who helped me through my question and went above and beyond with fleshing out the mechanics for me. After a bit of finagling on my end I actually have it sort of working. He finally tapped out after I asked one too many questions (understandably) but man oh man I REALLY wanted to credit him. No idea what his user name was. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438456/10275226) approach more or less solved all my issues (and a few future ones):

Answer (score 0):

Probably is better to define an associative array where keys are display names ("Poncho", "Cigarillo") and values are the object you actually declared as variables.

Something like:

```
var character01 = {
    inventory: {
        "Poncho" : {
            name: "Poncho",
            value: 3,
            use: function() {}
         },

        "Cigarillo" : {
        ...
        },

        "Bullet" : {
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

allows you can access everything, for example:

```
character1.inventory["Poncho"].value
```

and you should get "3".

Comment: In your approach, how would I push `"Poncho" : {
            name: "Poncho",
            value: 3,
            use: function() {}
         },` into character01.inventory

Comment: Just do: `character1.inventory["Poncho"] = { name: "Poncho", value: 3, use: function() {} }` or   `character1.inventory.Poncho = { name: "Poncho", value: 3, use: function() {} }`

Comment: And you can delete it by doing `delete character1.inventory.Poncho`

Comment: Last question, but on point, this approach (and my original) is probably no good if I intend to have multiples of the exact same item, except the exact same items could have differing values. For example identical flashlights with differing battery power, or two matching snub-nosed revolvers on the ground except one is loaded with 2 bullets and another with 6, or say three same brand cigarette packs in my inventory but one has 12 cigs, one has 4 cigs and one has 0. IOW same item types that can themselves contain other items would need a different approach all together I'd guess?

Comment: You can model same item "instances" with the approach above, using different keys "gun1" and "gun2" or you may also nesting items inside items: so you may have something like inventory: {"gun": { "gun1": {...}, "gun2": {...}}}. Alternatively if the model is complex you should distinguish between item classes and instances. However if you need a dictionary with name indexes you need use associative arrays.

Comment: OK but the amount of "guns" in the world is dynamic.I cant manually label them gun1, gun2, etc. Not sure how to create two (100?) guns into the world and have them loaded with independent amounts of ammo at any given time. Identical items except a single dynamic value that changes throughout the game. Durability is another good example. Many identical sticks... they all break after 20 hits... one club has 10 hits left, one has 5 hits left, one has 0, one has 20, etc. Cant quite figure out how to move forward on this concept. A quick code snippet on how to start would be invaluable friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code above to use arrays of same objects. For example:

```
var character01 = {
    inventory: {
        "Gun" : [
            {
                name: "Gun",
                value: 1,
                use: function() {}
            },
            {
                name: "Gun",
                value: 0,
                use: function() {}
            },        
            {
                name: "Gun",
                value: 3,
                use: function() {}
            }
        ],

        "Poncho" : [
            {
                name: "Poncho",
                value: 1,
                use: function() {}
            },
            {
                name: "Poncho",
                value: 2,
                use: function() {}
            },        
            {
                name: "Poncho",
                value: 3,
                use: function() {}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Of course to refer items, you may scan arrays or refer them directly through variables.