# How to create multiple identical same named containers, that can contain (and retain) varying items/amounts

Tags: javascript

So... I have created a bunch of "items" in the following manner, which works wonderfully for me in a lot of ways. In fact much of my code is based on this structure (a truncated list):

```
const items = {
  Pearls: {
    worth: 100,
    color: "white",
    use: // do something
  },
  Oyster: {
    pearlsInside: 6,
    something: "whatever"
  }
};
```

Then I have a players inventory set up like this:

```
const player = {
    someVariable: "thingamabob",
    inventory: [
    ]
};
```

When a player finds and gets an Oyster or a Pearl from the ground I push that item (name string) into the players "inventory array" and then behind the scenes I let them access/use the corresponding items values from the "items object".

Easy-peasy, works great, except one problem... if a player finds TWO Oysters on the ground, picks one up and removes 3 Pearls from inside it and then drops it back on the ground, if the player later picks up both Oysters they will **both** now have 3 Pearls (the previously unpicked up Oyster should still have 6).

This is a non issue for the Pearls item as it itself is not a "container" so to speak, there can be a hundred Pearls on the ground and a player can get them, use them and drop them as they please with no consequence... this is to say a Pearl is a Pearl is a Pearl, and this is working swimmingly for me on my end.

But when I got into that Oyster I realized I will need multiple items of the exact same name/type that have the ability to contain varying amounts of Pearls.

Bear in mind the players UI would only ever call an Oyster an Oyster in all instances - for example the ground or inventory would never display in game "Oyster1, Oyster2, Oyster666" - it would be "Oyster, Oyster, Oyster" or "3 Oysters". It's only upon further examination one may find the contents differing.

So... how bad am I going to have to mess up my current item structure to achieve "same named containers"?

If it helps, I suppose the answer to this question could help solve - how do you have 2 identical "flashlights" in a room, but each with varying degrees of battery power -- OR -- "You find four gold Colt 1911's with mother of pearl grips on the ground" (each with different amounts of ammo loaded in their clips) -- OR -- (maybe) how do you have multiple occurrences of treasure chests that are all simply seen/known as "chest" in game, that all contain various loot.

I'm guessing more of a mental block for me at this point, coupled with the fear that I went too far down the road with my current item/inventory structure/system and will now have to significantly revamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over thinking it, of course.

No GUID / UUID, no Symbols, no super sorcery.

Generating a unique ID for an object of the same name is as easy as making the global (what could be more global than a unique ID for every object in a game world)  function:

`function generateId() {
    return idid += 1;
}`

And then create a new item like so:

`function create(){
    var item = new NewItem( {id: generateId(), name: "Widget", power: 6, energy: 0} );
}`

that then pushes through a constructor as such:

`function NewItem(item) {
    this.item = item;
}`

Then you push each of these newly created items into your "all items in world" array as objects with tons of properties to reference as needed.

Among other things, this allows 100 'widgets' to be floating around in game each with a different ID which means one widget can have energy: 0 but another 'widget' can have energy: 69 as the game progresses.

Done and done. On to the next massive problem.... TO BE CONTINUED...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand your question, but this might help.

If you use ES6 (since you are using **const** I guess you are) you can use [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Symbol).

> Symbols are new to JavaScript in ECMAScript 2015. A Symbol is a unique
>   and immutable primitive value and may be used as the key of an Object
>   property. In some programming languages, Symbols are
>   called atoms. For more details see Symbol and the Symbol object
>   wrapper in JavaScript.

Comment: "Symbol" seems pretty cool, researching now. As I read through all the explanation/documentation it does make me wonder, do you know off hand of any examples of it being used in practice (Jfiddles and such)?

Comment: To be honest I struggle to fully understand how to implement it, but seems right for your use case :)

Comment: Please let me know if you succeed and upload your code :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using IDs for everything in your world. You can give them a type and each type would have a display name and other meta-data, but each instance of the object can then be uniquely identified.

Try searching for `GUID / UUID in Javascript` if you need help generating IDs.

Comment: funny thing, I started with each item having an ID and a "name", but foresaw issues having an object oyster with a name: "oyster", plus the redundancy of calling oyster to get its name "oyster, so I went to the variable name is its name setup I shared. That being said... I am hand stamping all my objects ahead of time in items{}. My issue is, I have no idea how many oysters will be in the world or dropped in the same room or in the same inventory, and I would never want to hand crank 100 of the same objects each with just a differing ID value. So how should I approach?

Comment: as you say, I definitely do want "each instance of the object uniquely identified", but I want to achieve this off of a single 'super object' (in my example code) if you will. So agree with your approach, not comprehending how to implement.

Comment: What you call a "single super object" is essentially what's called a "class". I don't know what your skill level is, but you might want to study Object Oriented Programming some more. Although not required in JS, it's a good approach for the system you describe. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS

Comment: Appreciated. I am definitely learning to crawl before I walk and would prolly dive deep into prototypes before classes, however I will research this for sure. But here is the thing gnawing at me... I know that there were some robust, at least text based adventures, with inventories that had cloned items that could have differing values (a player can carry 2 leather pouches, each with a diff amount of gold pieces in it) prior to 2015. That is probably where my quest lays... hmmm...

Comment: It sure is possible to do with plain old objects, keep in mind that what goes in your inventory array are *instances*, conforming to a certain prototype. In other words you define their *structure* once and then you have to make *new* objects that eventually go in the inventory, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Created a second answer to illustrate the above

Answer (score 0):

Represent collections with arrays instead of objects. Then you can have multiples of the same item inside that array. If you then give every item the same properties, you have easy comparison. To differentiate between items, use ids.

```js
const inventory = [
  {
    color: "white",
    id: 1,
    name: "pearls",
    uses: [
      "buy",
      "craft",
      "trade",
      "sell"
    ],
    weight: 0.1,
    worth: 100
  },
  {
    color: "white",
    id: 2,
    name: "pearls",
    uses: [
      "buy",
      "craft",
      "trade",
      "sell"
    ],
    weight: 0.1,
    worth: 100
  },
  {
    color: "brown",
    id: 3,
    name: "wood",
    uses: [
      "buy",
      "craft",
      "trade",
      "sell"
    ],
    weight: 2,
    worth: 10
  }
];
const net_worth = inventory.reduce(( a, b ) => a + b.worth, 0 );
console.log( `two pearls and one wood are worth ${ net_worth }` );

const oyster = {
  color: "grey",
  id: 4,
  name: "oyster",
  uses: [
    "loot_pearls",
    "open"
  ],
  weight: 1,
  worth: 6
};
console.log( `opening the oyster gave you ${ oyster.worth } pearls` );
```

Comment: My "inventory" is an array. Also, not familiar with having "unnamed" objects - hurts my head a bit -- beyond that though -- what I am not grasping is how the differing ID is going to get affixed to the re-used object. This is to say I am creating all of my world items ahead of time, and I create a single Oyster that I want to see in multiplicity throughout the world. Would I instead have to create 100 Oyster objects and give each one of them a unique ID value by hand in my initial items{} list?

Comment: Also, not seeing off hand how I would push an item into your inventory array (if a player picks up a pearl). It looks like i would have to push 6 properties/values at once? Sorry, so set in my initial approach I am lost by this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of Oyster and Pearl prototypes and how to instantiate them.

```js
// Some helper functions
function randomNum(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

function randomColor() {
  var colors = ['white', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow'];
  return colors[randomNum(3)];
}

// The Pearl prototype
function Pearl(worth, color, usageCallback) {
  this.worth = worth;
  this.color = color;
  this.use = usageCallback;
}
// Replace the default toString() function just for fun
Pearl.prototype.toString = function() {
 return 'A ' + this.color + ' colored pearl worth ' + this.worth; 
}

// The Oyster prototype
function Oyster(pearlsInside, something) {
  this.pearls = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < pearlsInside; i++) {
   this.pearls.push(new Pearl(randomNum(100), randomColor(), function() {}))
  }
  this.something = something;
}
// Replace the default toString() function just for fun
Oyster.prototype.toString = function() {
 var description = 'The oyster contains ' + this.pearls.length + ' pearls: ';
  this.pearls.forEach(function(pearl) {
   description += pearl + ', ';
  });
  return description;
}

// Here we instantiate our new objects
var oyster1 = new Oyster(6, 'Whatever');
var oyster2 = new Oyster(3, 'Whatever');

// And then we can use them
var container = document.getElementById('pearls');
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oyster1 + ''));
container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
container.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oyster2 + ''));

// (or log them as strings)
console.log(oyster1 + '');
console.log(oyster2 + '');
```

```html
<div id="pearls"></div>
```

Comment: First off thank you for this, secondly I will take care of you at some point, promise... thirdly feel free to tap out at anytime, I have a tendency to do that to people... next...

Comment: I have a grip on generating new objects into the world. My issue is twofold after generation. (A) I don't know how many oysters will populate the world. I can't instantiate them as you've shown or I'd have `var oyster100 = '. 

And (B) below...

Comment: (B) Not looking to get random amounts of pearls in the oyster "at creation/generation". Need oysters to hold differing amounts of pearls as a player adds/removes them throughout the game.  NUTSHELL: There are two 'dynamically generated' identical sacks (oysters) in inventory, heck even one on the ground. They're all the same sack, except each one has differing amount of coins (pearls) in it cuz the player's been adding() and removing() coins from each sack, as well as dropping/getting sacks to see they each retained their individual (ever changing) amount of coins as the player left it.

Comment: I may have done a bad job of explaining my predicament in my OP. I've created several working inventory systems. Including one where I'm filling a sack (oyster) with coins (pearls), removing some of the coins, dropping the sack, and picking it back up to see it has the amount of coins I left in it. However, it all went bad when I introduced two matching sacks in game. Now when I manipulate the first sacks contents, the second sacks contents are same as the first. I understand why this is happening. Getting around it is the intent of my question. And remember amount of sacks is dynamic.

Comment: The randomness and instantiating them into a variable are just to be able to print something; of course in your own code you would have your game logic doing all of that. What I tried to demonstrate is the difference between something that *describes a type* and something that *is of a certain type*. That being said, Javascript can be tricky with scope sometimes, where things can both point to the same value unexpectedly; if you run into such a problem I'd recommend starting a new question with a minimal jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem.